# How do I call the readStudents method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Probability {
   public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {

      String fileName;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
      fileName = input.nextLine();

      System.out.println("How many students do you have listed in the file?");
      int numStudents = input.nextInt();

      input.close();

      Student[] students = new Student[numStudents];

      //readStudents(students, numStudents, fileName);
      // calls the readStudents method

      //Student myStudent = new Student(name, gpa);
      //System.out.println(myStudent);
      // creates and prints an object of the Student class

      for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
         System.out.println("students [" + i + "] = " + students[i]);
      } // for

   } // main

   public static void readStudents(Student[] students, int numStudents, String fileName)throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

      while(fin.hasNext()){
         String name = fin.next();
         double gpa = fin.nextDouble();
         students[0] = new Student(name, gpa);
      } // while

      fin.close();

   } // readStudents

} // class
```

I am trying to read from this data file: datafile.txt

Amy 3.5

Steven 3.2

Oscar 3.8

Tim 2.7

Ann 2.1

Jimmy 3.9

I am also using this program:

```
public class Student {

      private String name;
      private double gpa;

   public Student(String name, double gpa){

      this.name = name;
      this.gpa = gpa;

   } //Student

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }
   public double getGPA(){
      return gpa;
   }

   public void setName(){
      this.name = name;
   }
   public void setGPA(){
      this.gpa = gpa;
   }

   public String toString(){
      return("The student's name is " + name + "\n" + "The student's grade point average is " + gpa);
   }

} //class
```

You can see that I tried
`//readStudents(students, numStudents, fileName);` and

```
Student myStudent = new Student(name, gpa);
System.out.println(myStudent);
```

But neither worked.

When I tried `//readStudents(students, numStudents, fileName);`, this is the error message I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: datafile (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:220)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
    at Probability.readStudents(Probability.java:44)
    at Probability.main(Probability.java:29)
```

And when I tried

```
Student myStudent = new Student(name, gpa);
System.out.println(myStudent);
```

this is the error message I got:

```
Probability.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
      Student myStudent = new Student(name, gpa);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: class Probability
Probability.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
      Student myStudent = new Student(name, gpa);
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable gpa
  location: class Probability
2 errors
```

This is what my professor wants me to accomplish:

Implement a class named “Student” with the following properties:

name: String type

gpa: double type

and the following methods:

one constructor `Student(String name, double gpa)`

getters and setters for each attribute

`toString()`:which prints on the screen the attributes of the class (one attribute per line)

Write a main method in a separate class with the following methods:

`public static void readStudents(Student[] students, int numStudents, String fileName)`: accept the name of a data file of students and returns a 1D array containing the students in the file.

The main method should:

Ask the user for how many students(1pts) and the name of the data file and then call readStudents to get the list of students from the data file.
Display the array.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty so your file not found exception is likely due to not having the correct file path to the file you are trying to open. You are trying to open 'datafile.txt' but where is it in your directory structure? If it is at the root of your project than 'datafile.txt' which implys './datafile.txt' (i.e. look in current dir for datafile.txt) would work.

However say you have a folder at the root of your project called 'data' and your datafile.txt is in this folder. Now to open this file you need a relative path from the root of your project i.e. 'data/datafile.txt' (same as './data/datafile.txt').

Your other errors 'cannot find symbol' for name and gpa are due to the fact that you have not defined variables name and gpa in main to reference in the Student constructor. You would need something like:

```java
String name = "the_name_you_want";
double gpa = 4.0;
```

**before** your constructor to be able to use name and gpa like that.

You could alternatively call the constructor like so:

```java
Student a = new Student("a", 4.0);
```

Or you could set these members on a default student object if you provide a default Student constructor:

**Add Default Student Constructor to your student class i.e.**

```java
public Student(){}
```

^^Note this would be in addition to your current constructor which is supported due to a feature called **Constructor Overloading**.

**Now you could make a student like this:**

```java
Student a = new Student();
a.name = "a";
a.gpa = 4.0;
```

**ALSO: your loop for readStudents will only ever give you an array of one student because you only ever set array[0] to a new student. Try this instead:**

```java
int i = 0;
while (fin.hasNext()) {
    String name = fin.next();
    double gpa = fin.nextDouble();
    students[i++] = new Student(name, gpa);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I like your suggestions, but the professor wants me to be able to take the name and gpa values from the data file

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track except for a few modifications. As stated in other answers, file not found is because the wrong path to the file is being provided. Try using the full filepath. For your next concern, from the requirements you have described, this is how the program should be:

```java
public class Probability {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
        fileName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many students do you have listed in the file?");
        int numStudents = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        Student[] students = readStudents(numStudents, fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("students [" + i + "] = " + students[i]);
        }
    }

    public static Student[] readStudents(int numStudents, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Student[] students = new Student[numStudents];
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        int i=0;
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            String name = fin.next();
            double gpa = fin.nextDouble();
            students[i] = new Student(name, gpa);
            i++;
        }
        fin.close();
        return students;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```java
students [0] = The student's name is Amy
The student's grade point average is 3.5
students [1] = The student's name is Steven
The student's grade point average is 3.2
students [2] = The student's name is Oscar
The student's grade point average is 3.8
students [3] = The student's name is Tim
The student's grade point average is 2.7
students [4] = The student's name is Ann
The student's grade point average is 2.1
students [5] = The student's name is Jimmy
The student's grade point average is 3.9
```

As you have stated, the function *readStudents* is supposed to return an array to the calling method.

> Write a main method in a separate class with the following methods:
>   public static void readStudents(Student[] students, int numStudents,
>   String fileName): accept the name of a data file of students and
>   returns a 1D array containing the students in the file.

If you pass the array as an argument to *readStudents*, there is no need to return it to the calling method since java will pass the array by reference. This makes this program valid as well:

```java
public class Probability {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
        fileName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many students do you have listed in the file?");
        int numStudents = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
       Student[] students = new Student[numStudents];
        readStudents(students,numStudents, fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("students [" + i + "] = " + students[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void readStudents(Student[] students, int numStudents, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        int i=0;
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            String name = fin.next();
            double gpa = fin.nextDouble();
            students[i] = new Student(name, gpa);
            i++;
        }
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

It depends on which one you deem suitable for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error: FileNotFoundException
This error is caused because the system can not find the file you specified. Make sure to give it the correct path. Your starting path is most likely the src folder.

Your second error: cannot find symbol
This error is because you have not initialized `name` and `gpa` before calling the constructor. Changing the code to the following should fix the problem:

```
    String name = "Student 1";
    double gpa = 3.2;
    Student myStudent = new Student(name, gpa);
    System.out.println(myStudent);
```